# Log4J with Wildfly in IntelliJ not working as expected

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss, log4j, wildfly

I try to use log4j with Wildfly 10 but I get not the result expected.

My `log4j.properties` contains following:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, STDOUT

log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n %highlight{%-5p %c %x - %m%n}{FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=black, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue}
```

But I get following result in the debug view of IntelliJ:

```
}{FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=black,
DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue}404335 [default task-9] 
%highlight{ERROR stderr  -  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
```

What is wrong?

(I use local deployment)

Comment: Is there a stack trace with the error?

Comment: The error here is only the line example but it‘s the same for everything else

Comment: Have you tried removing your `log4j.properties`? It shouldn't be required for log4j to work.